# How can i add custom menu in QGIS Using python

Tags: qgis, python

I am tried to add a custom main menu in QGIS Desktop Application. Here I am already added custom sub menu in QGIS but I want to add a custom main menu in QGIS using Python. 
See the blow image.
[image]

Comment: Perhaps this post might help: [Adding new menu item to QGIS Desktop app](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/136267/adding-new-menu-item-to-qgis-desktop-app)