# Can you build a login window in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, pyqgis

Can you build a login window before loading QGIS interface?

I use QGIS 2.8
[image]

I just built message windows when loading QGIS interface, but no more.

Comment: You're asking two different questions. Please split them into two different questions in GIS.SE. Only in this way you'll get proper answers. Additionaly, I encourage you to write your question in English, so that you'll reach a wider set of users. (Btw., I didn't downvoted your question).

Comment: Please don't use ALL CAPS in your question titles.

Comment: As for the first question you asked, see: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/136267/adding-new-menu-item-to-qgis-desktop-app/136272